# bash running nc with ampersand terminates program

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipeline

I want to run nc via & and then manually feed data in stdin from /proc filesystem whenever I want. so the problem is:

if I run `nc 127.0.0.1 1234 &`

program runs in background and I can write in stdin whatever I want. but, if I create test.sh and add

```
#!/bin/bash
nc 127.0.0.1 1234 &
sleep 20
```

it connects to 1234 and terminates immediately (doesn't even wait for 20 seconds). why? I was suspecting it gets it's stdin written from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

The bash manpage states:

```
   If  a  command  is  followed  by a & and job control is not active, the
   default standard input for the command is  the  empty  file  /dev/null.
   Otherwise,  the  invoked  command  inherits the file descriptors of the
   calling shell as modified by redirections.
```

If you call `nc 127.0.0.1 1234 < /dev/null` outside a shell script (with job control) it will result in the same.

You can change your bash script like this to make it work:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc 127.0.0.1 1234 < /dev/stdin &
sleep 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your purpose right, you want to feed data manually to nc which will be sent to client.

You can use named pipes for this purpose.

`cat /tmp/f | ./parser.sh  2>&1 | nc -lvk 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f`

where `/tmp/f` is a pipe made using `mkfifo /tmp/f`

whatever you want to feed to `nc` can be echo-ed in `parser.sh`

Comment: thanks for giving another solution but more than that I wanted to understand why nc terminates in my case

Comment: try flag `-lk` which allows it not to terminate as soon as it receives one connection and wait for other connection @JaniBaramidze